# Knockout.js 1.3.0 IF statement syntax when using containerless control flow

Tags: syntax, knockout.js

Here's example from Steve Sanderson's blog demonstrating a containerless IF statement in knockout:

```
<h3>Products</h3>

<ul>
    <li><strong>Here is a static header item</strong></li>
    <!-- ko foreach: products -->
    <li>
        <em data-bind="text: name"></em>
        <!-- ko if: manufacturer -->        
            &mdash; made by <span data-bind="text: manufacturer.company"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

How would I make the IF statement more complex. I am trying the following and it doesn't work (always returns false):

```
<!-- ko if: PlanStateName == 'Draft' -->
<div>This plan is a draft!</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

How would one accomplish this?

Comment: I can't answer my question for 5 hours, but until then here's a comment! I need parentheses on my variable name: PlanStateName() == 'Draft' works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out I made a rookie mistake. Here's the working code:

```
<!-- ko if: PlanStateName() == 'Draft' -->
<div>This plan is a draft!</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Since the variables are wrappered by knockout, the parentheses on PlanStateName are required to access the underlying data.

Comment: Glad you found it.  Even with experience, this is the easiest error to make using KO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the logical statement with {}.

See http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/nvYdf/55/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this out with the containerless IF statement and it doesn't work. Not sure if this can be considered a ko.js bug or not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/mkCze/  It's working for me.  Sorry didn't give you correct demo first time.

Comment: Nothing's displayed after Xbox in this fiddle for me, presumably because of breakage on the Sony product (where the containerless if statement is). I tried it on Chrome and FireFox. What browser are you using?

Comment: Actually, XBox is all it displays.  It was a quick app to answer your question. I use chrome.

Comment: [This updated and working Fiddle explained it for me](http://jsfiddle.net/FMsRS/1). Thanks for taking the time to build a varied data structure!